# How Can I Create Events With Fullcalendar

Tags: calendar

I’m new to stackexchange and heard it’s a good place to discuss code/developing etc.  I’m currently working on a particular visual force page creation, in the Salesforce platform.  So far, this is the code I have come up with, however when I input into Salesforce Visual Page, we still do not have the functionality we need.  Does anyone have experience with creating Visual Force pages and or calendars and maybe could advise what the issue with current code seems to be?  We are trying to create a calendar which allows our users to post events and also RSVP to events.   I’m relatively new to both Visual Force concepts, as well as to the forum here. The codes show a calendar, but when we click on date nothing happens, we can not add events. We still don't know how to create a RSVP button yet. Thanks much.

```
<link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarCSS}" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarPrintCSS}" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.FullCalendar, '/fullcalendar-2.0.3/lib/moment.min.js')}"  />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="{!$Resource.fullCalendarMinJS}"></script>



<script>

    //We need to wrap everything in a doc.ready function so that the code fires after the DOM is loaded

    $(document).ready(function() {   

        //Call the fullCallendar method. You can replace the '#calendar' with the ID of the dom element where you want the calendar to go. 

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {

                left: 'prev,next today',

                center: 'title',

                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'

            },

          editable: true,  

            eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.qtip({
        content: {
            title: {
                text: event.title
            },
            text: '<span class="title">Date: </span>' + ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'MM/dd/yy')) + '<br><span class="title">Time: </span>' + ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'hh:mmtt')) + '<span class="title"> to </span>' + ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, 'hh:mmtt')) + '<br><span class="title">Event: </span>' + event.Name + '<br><span class="title">Driver: </span>' + event.driver + '<br><span class="title">Location: </span>' + event.location + '<br><span class="title">Commidity: </span>' + event.commidity + '<br><span class="title">Description: </span>' + event.description
        },
        show: {
            solo: true
        },
        //hide: { when: 'inactive', delay: 3000 }, 
        position: {
            corner: {
                target: 'topLeft',
                tooltip: 'bottomRight'
            }
        },
        style: {
            width: 200,
            padding: 5,
            color: 'black',
            textAlign: 'left',
            border: {
                width: 1,
                radius: 3
            },

            classes: {
                tooltip: 'ui-widget',
                tip: 'ui-widget',
                title: 'ui-widget-header',
                content: 'ui-widget-content'
            }
        }
    });

},

dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    var $dialogContent = $("#event_edit_container");

    y = date.getFullYear();
    m = date.getMonth();
    d = date.getDate();

    h1 = date.getHours();
    m1 = date.getMinutes();

    h2 = h1 + 1;
    m2 = m1;

    calEvent = {
        title: 'New Calendar Event',
        editable: true,
        start: new Date(y, m, d, h1, m1),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, h2, m2),
        allDay: false
    }
        }

        });



    });



</script>



<!--some styling. Modify this to fit your needs-->

<style>

    #cal-options {float:left;}

    #cal-legend { float:right;}

    #cal-legend ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}

    #cal-legend ul li {margin:0;padding:5px;float:left;}

    #cal-legend ul li span {display:block; height:16px; width:16px; margin-right:4px; float:left; border-radius:4px;}

    #calendar {margin-top:20px;}

    #calendar a:hover {color:#fff !important;}



    .fc-event-inner {padding:3px;}

    .event-birthday {background:#56458c;border-color:#56458c;}

    .event-campaign {background:#cc9933;border-color:#cc9933;}

    .event-personal {background:#1797c0;border-color:#1797c0;}

</style>



<apex:sectionHeader title="My Calendar Example"/>

<apex:outputPanel id="calPanel">

    <apex:form >

        <div id="cal-options">

            <apex:commandButton value="{!IF(includeMyEvents,'Hide My Events','Show My Events')}" action="{!toggleMyEvents}"/>

        </div>

        <div id="cal-legend">

            <ul>

                <li><span class="event-birthday"></span>Contact's Birthdays</li>

                <li><span class="event-campaign"></span>Campaigns</li>

                <li style="{!IF(includeMyEvents,'','display:none')}"><span class="event-personal"></span>My Events</li>

            </ul>

            <div style="clear:both;"><!--fix floats--></div>

        </div>

        <div style="clear:both;"><!--fix floats--></div>

        <div id="calendar"></div>

    </apex:form>

</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange. To help people help you, it would be much appriciated that you do a little bit more effort than just pasting in your code. How is your code not working ? What have you done to figure out what parts are not working ?  Is it a layout or functional issue ? Please consider updating your question and answering some of these questions.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  We really need some more details in order to try to help.  As of right now, it seems like you have found some code (you didn't write) and its not working the way you want it to.  What is it supposed to do, how is it not doing that? etc, etc.  As @SamuelDeRycke pointed out, put a bit more effort in and we would love to help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The codes show a calendar, but when we click on date can not add events. We still don't know how to create a RSVP button yet.